# MYSQL - select all time high score

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, max

Assuming we have a table like below

```
   id   |   name   |  userid  |  score  |      datestamp      |
   ------------------------------------------------------------
    1   |   john   |    1     |   44    |  2013-06-10 14:25:55 
    2   |   mary   |    2     |   59    |  2013-06-10 09:25:51 
    3   |   john   |    1     |   38    |  2013-06-10 21:25:15 
    4   |   elvis  |    3     |   19    |  2013-06-10 07:25:18
    5   |   john   |    1     |   100   |  2013-06-14 07:25:18
```

I want to select the all time high-score of each user.

so for example if the player john have played ten rounds in 2013-06-10 and his score is 430 in total for that day. and in 2013-06-14 he plays 16 rounds and his scores is 1220 in total for that day. i want to display the the best score of user john, and so on for the others players. in the example above johns best score was 2013-06-14 with score 1220.

Detailed example:
If user John plays 3 rounds in 2013-06-10. First round he scores 44, second time he scores 38 and third time he scores 55. His total score for that day is 137. And on the next day 2013-06-11 he plays 5 rounds with a total score of 220. In this example his best total score so far is 220. So it should group all scores for each day to a total. And then compare this total with other days total and display the highest total of that user

Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe i'm missing something, but isn't john's best score 100 on 2013-04-14 in your example? Where are you getting the 1220 from?

Comment: @gordonk - He want to group score by each datestamp. And the given example doesn't contain all records.

Comment: @hims056 that is corrent.

Comment: So wait, you don't want the "all time high score" but the "daily high score sum" of each user?

Comment: @gordonk No, it's the all time high score I want. For example. If user John plays 3 rounds in 2013-06-10. First round he scores 44, second time he scores 38 and third time he scores 55. His total for that day is 137. And on the next day 2013-06-11 he plays 5 rounds with a total of 220. In this example his best total score is 220. So it should group all scores for each day to a total. And then compare this total with other days total and display the highest total of that user.

Comment: @Dreni: ok that makes more sense, imo "all time high score" is a little misleading, as it leads us to believe you want the highest single score from a user, not the highest scoring day of a user (what i meant with daily sum). Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: You would be wise to include an additional `DATE` column in your table, with a compound index across it and the `userid`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT userId, name, MAX(score) as highScore
FROM (
    SELECT userID, name, SUM(score) as score, date(datestamp) as scoreDate
    FROM TableName
    GROUP BY userID, scoreDate
  ) dailyScores
GROUP BY userId
```

The inner query fetches the totals of each user's scores on each date (timestamp converted to date to remove time information), the outer query then gets the highest total score of each date for each user.

I took the liberty of basing on J W's fiddle, and I added another row to your example data so the functionality is obvious, try it out here:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6bea/3

Comment: The `scoreDate` selected in the outer query will be indeterminate.

Comment: oh yeah thanks for pointing that out! i've taken it out, doesn't seem like he wants it in his result anyway. @Dreni: is this query any help?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    Tablename a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  userID, MAX(score) max_Score
            FROM    TableName
            GROUP   BY userID
        ) b ON a.userID = b.userID AND
                a.score = b.max_Score
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a7d2/2)

For faster searching, you need to have compound index on `(userid, score)`. Here's how to implement it:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName ADD INDEX (userid, score)
```

Comment: Your query would be excessively slow on a MySQL database when there are many users.

Comment: @Aron how? did you test it?

Comment: Actually just looked at your SQLFiddler demo. It works by creating the inner subquery as a temp table, hence slow.

Comment: @Aron it's because there are no keys define on it. Try this, and read the execution: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/095e8/1

Comment: Interesting...Generally speaking I find MySQL has extremely poor subquery performance. When does it actually use indices and when does it actually create a temp table?

Comment: @Aron then teach me how to solve this problem without using subquery. We all know MySQL doesn't support windowing functions.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28420/discussion-between-aron-and-j-w)

Comment: @J W I already have index on userid and score. I just did not include it in my example. Can you please have a look on my edited question. The detailed example.